# jqueryui 1.10.3 datepicker format using . as separator

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have inherited some code that appears to use jqueryui 1.10.3 to incorporate a datepicker.
When I click the textbox to bring the datepicker up and choose a date, the format looks like

`21.03.2020`

However, if I click on the textbox again the format is

`21/03/2020`

The slash is the desired functionality. When the initial date is selected I want it to display as `dd/mm/yyyy`. How can I stop the date parts being separated by `.`
I have tried examining the jquery-ui-1.10.3 file to see if I can work out where the `.` separator is being applied but I haven't been able to come up with anything.

Comment: Please see https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-formats

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your web page or script section you should have code that looks like the code below.

This is where you can set your date time picker format. Look at the format date section.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
             $("#<%= TextBoxName.ClientID %>").datetimepicker({
                 dayOfWeekStart: 1,
                 lang: 'en',
                 startDate: '<%= TextBoxName.Text %>',
                 step: 30,
                 formatTime: 'H:i',
                 formatDate: 'Y.m.d'
             });
         });
```

See more help here: [jquery datetime picker](https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/)